# Variables not updating properly

Tags: java, logic

This is a logic problem, so I haven't really been able to find anything on what I'm doing wrong unfortunately. For almost a day now I've been trying to figure out why the centerX and centerY variables are not updating properly for the player object in the CoreProcesses file.  Each time i hit the appropriate button they are supposed to increment or decrement by the appropriate amount, but for some reason it remains the same no matter what I have tried.  I'm at a complete loss here.  I just need pointed in the right direction, and I thank everyone in advance.  Below are the files

Player.java

```
package gameloopconcepts;

public class Player {

    /**
     *  Constants
     */
    final int MOVESPEED = 20;

    /**
     *  Class wide variables
     */

    // Player Draw Coordinates
    private int centerX = 90;
    private int centerY = 390;

    // Handles updating draw coordinates
    private int speedX = 0;
    private int speedY = 0;

    /**
     * Update method for game loop
     */

    public void update(){
        // Updates draw coordinates
        centerX += speedX;

    }

    /**
     * Movement Methods
     */

    public void moveUp(){
        speedY = -MOVESPEED;
    }

    public void moveDown(){
        speedY = MOVESPEED;
    }

    public void moveRight(){
        speedX = 20;
    }

    public void moveLeft(){
        speedX = -20;
    }

    public void stop(){
        speedX = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Getters and setters for variabes
     */

    public int getCenterX(){
        return centerX;
    }

    public int getCenterY(){
        return centerY;
    }

    public void setCenterX(int centerX){
        this.centerX = centerX;
    }

    public void setCenterY(int centerY){
        this.centerY = centerY;
    }

}
```

CoreProcesses.java

```
package gameloopconcepts;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;

public class CoreProcesses extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    // Constants

    // Class wide variables
    private Player player;
    private Image image, character;
    private Graphics second;
    private URL docBase;

    /**
     * Initializes the applet
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        // Sets window size
        setSize(480, 800);

        // Sets window background color
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        // Sets the window to focus at the start
        setFocusable(true);

        // Sets the key listener
        addKeyListener(this);

        // Sets the applet frame and the title
        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("ORIGIN ALPHA");

        // Gets document base
        try{
            docBase = getDocumentBase();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }

        // Sets up images
        character = getImage(docBase, "/Users/StudioAccount/Documents/Development/Workspaces/IntelliJ Idea/Test/src/assets/player.png");

    }

    /**
     * Starts the applet and assigns any necessary game objects
     */
    @Override
    public void start() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.start();
        player = new Player();

        // Defines the main thread and starts it
        Thread mainThread = new Thread();
        mainThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Main Loop
        while(true){
            player.update();
            repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g){
        if(image == null){
            image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            second = image.getGraphics();
        }

        second.setColor(getBackground());
        second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        second.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(second);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(character, player.getCenterX(), player.getCenterY(), this);
    }

    /**
     * Key Listener events
     */
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Test logs for key events
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                player.moveUp();
                System.out.println(player.getCenterY());
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                player.moveDown();
                System.out.println(player.getCenterY());
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                player.moveLeft();
                System.out.println(player.getCenterX());
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                player.moveRight();
                System.out.println(player.getCenterX());
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Test logs for key events
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                System.out.println("Stop moving character up");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                System.out.println("Stop moving character down");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                player.stop();
                System.out.println("Stop moving character left");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                player.stop();
                System.out.println("Stop moving character right");
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

centerX and centerY should be going up or down by 20 on the corresponding button presses.

Comment: `speedX` and `centerX` are not the same thing.

Comment: @Makoto What I need to happen is if moveRight is called, it adds 20 to speedX then adds speedX to centerX during the update method, and on key release stop() gets called to reset speedX to zero and prevent infinite movement on the update loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `CoreProcesses` `run` method isn't being executed, because you didn't specify the `Runnable` object in the `Thread` creation.

So, instead of

```
Thread mainThread = new Thread();
```

you should have

```
Thread mainThread = new Thread(this);
```

Also, the way you have it, if you press a key once, you will see a giant increase of the X position, because this method is actually executed many, many times.

What you probably want is to `update` the player imediatly on the `keyPressed` event.

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_W:
            player.moveUp();
            System.out.println(player.getCenterY());
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_S:
            player.moveDown();
            System.out.println(player.getCenterY());
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:
            player.moveLeft();
            System.out.println(player.getCenterX());
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:
            player.moveRight();
            System.out.println(player.getCenterX());
            break;
    }

    player.update();
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I never even thought to check that thank you.